# How to make a mute command in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a bot with `Discord.js` and was wondering how I could add a mute function. I would like the bot to give you a predefined muted role for a certain amount of time, and then remove it.

Comment: To make a mute command, you have to give a "mute" role to the player, and then with a `.setTimeout()` remove it. Create a role with no permission, so they can't write in any channel.

Comment: how do i add a role to a mentioned player? can you give the code please or a tutorial? sorry. i'm new to discord bot dvelopment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you need to make a good `mute` command:

- The [`GuildMemberRoleManager#add()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) Function
- The [`setTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) Function
- The [`GuildMemberRoleManager#remove()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=remove) Function

There are many other features you should take into consideration when making the command, such as permission restrictions, confirmation messages, etc. However, these are the bare basics.

---

First, you need to get the `Muted` role.

```js
// get the role by id:
const mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('<Muted Role ID>');

// or, if you can't get the id:
const mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(
 (role) => role.name === 'Muted'
);

// if there is no `Muted` role, send an error
if (!mutedRole)
 return message.channel.send('There is no Muted role on this server');
```

Then, you must get [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object of the user you want to mute.

```js
// assuming you want the command to mention the target, for example: `!mute @user`
const target = message.mentions.members.first();
```

Now, you can give that user the `Muted` role.

```js
target.roles.add(mutedRole);
```

---

To take away the role after a bit of time, you need a delay function. The best function for that is [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp). After the `target.roles.add()` line:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  target.roles.remove(mutedRole); // remove the role
}, <time>)
```

Getting the specified amount of time will be tricky. `setTimeout()` only accepts milliseconds as a delay value. You could either:

- Just always trigger the command with an `ms` time argument
- Always trigger the command with a time value that isn't `ms`, such as seconds, hours, etc. Then, parse the given time to `ms` in the script
- Use a handy dandy `npm` package called [`ms`](https://npmjs.com/package/ms). You'll be able to use values such as `10s`, `12h`, `2d`, etc.

If you choose the first option, then you're pretty much finished with the command! Just replace `<time>` in the above snippet with `args[1]`, and everything should work.

If you chose the second option, then you'll need to do a bit more. If you chose to mute in seconds, replace `<time>` with `args[1] * 1000`. If you chose hour, replace it with `args[1] * 60000`, etc.

If you chose the third option, you can parse the time using the `ms` package by simply replacing `<time>` with `ms(args[1])`

Comment: where is args[1] coming from? how do I structure the command?